# C++ 3rd Person Camera in DirectX11

Tags: c++, camera, directx-11

Basically, I want to have my camera float behind a character (aCar) and stay behind it when it turns and such so that it is always floating behind the character, at the moment I have a camera that turns in the same direction as my character but I can't seem to make it stay behind relative to the direction they're facing at all.

I've found a tutorial here http://www.braynzarsoft.net/index.php?p=D3D11ThirdPersonCam
but that uses XMVECTORs which were being hilariously un-cooperative, on top of that it was unclear what some of the functions actually did mathematically

Without further ado, here is my code related to camera and the object it is meant to follow behind

Update method

```
XMFLOAT3 relativeMovement;
if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x57)) //W key press
{

    relativeVectorCalc(0, true); 
}
if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x53)) // S Key Press
{

    relativeVectorCalc(1, true);
}
if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x41)) //A Key Press
{
    relativeVectorCalc(3, true);
}
if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x44)) //D Key Press
{
    relativeVectorCalc(2, true);
}

if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x45)) //E Key Press
{
    CameraRotate(1);
    //relativeVectorCalc(2, false);
    aCar.at(0)->setWorld({ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, aCar.at(0)->getPos(), 0.0f, 0.001f, 0.0f);
} else if(GetAsyncKeyState(0x51)) //Q Key Press
{
    CameraRotate(0);
    //relativeVectorCalc(3, false);
    aCar.at(0)->setWorld({ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, aCar.at(0)->getPos(), 0.0f, -0.001f, 0.0f);
}



cam->CalculateViewProjection();

void Application::relativeVectorCalc(int k, bool P)
{

    XMFLOAT3 relativeMovement;
    XMFLOAT4 camAt = cam->GetAt();
    XMFLOAT4 camEye = cam->GetEye();

    //Finds the direction the player is facing and moves relative to that based on the key the    player pressed
    if (k == 0)
    {
        relativeMovement.x = (camAt.x - camEye.x); //Calculates the distance between the camera's center and its eye
        relativeMovement.y = 0.0f;
        relativeMovement.z = (camAt.z - camEye.z); //See above
    }
    else if (k == 1)
    {
        relativeMovement.x = 0 - (camAt.x - camEye.x);
        relativeMovement.y = 0.0f;
        relativeMovement.z = 0 - (camAt.z - camEye.z);
    }
    else if (k == 2)
    {
        relativeMovement.x = (camAt.z - camEye.z);
        relativeMovement.y = 0.0f;
        relativeMovement.z = 0 - (camAt.x - camEye.x);
    }
    else if (k == 3)
    {
        relativeMovement.x = 0 - (camAt.z - camEye.z);
        relativeMovement.y = 0.0f;
        relativeMovement.z = (camAt.x - camEye.x);
    }
    relativeMovement = (relativeMovement); //Makes the vector normalised

    //Here is where the speed of the movement is controlled via division
    relativeMovement.x = relativeMovement.x / 100; //slows down movement
    relativeMovement.z = relativeMovement.z / 100;

    if (P)
    {
        PlayerMove(relativeMovement);
        CameraMove(relativeMovement);
    }
    else if (!P)
    {
        CameraMove(relativeMovement);
    }

 }



 void Application::CameraMove(XMFLOAT3 straightMovementVector)
 {
XMFLOAT4 cameraEye = cam->GetEye();
XMFLOAT4 cameraAt = cam->GetAt();
cameraEye.x = cameraEye.x + straightMovementVector.x;
cameraEye.z = cameraEye.z + straightMovementVector.z;
cameraAt.x = cameraAt.x + straightMovementVector.x;
cameraAt.z = cameraAt.z + straightMovementVector.z;
cameraAt.y = aCar.at(0)->getPos().y + 3.0f;
cam->SetEye(cameraEye);
cam->SetAt(cameraAt);

 }



 void Application::PlayerMove(XMFLOAT3 move)
 {
    XMFLOAT3 p = aCar.at(0)->getPos();
    p.x = p.x + move.x;
    p.z = p.z + move.z;
    aCar.at(0)->setPos(p);
 }




 void Application::CameraRotate(int x)
 {
XMFLOAT4 camAt = cam->GetAt();
XMFLOAT4 camEye = cam->GetEye();
XMFLOAT3 carPos = aCar.at(0)->getPos();

XMFLOAT2 dist = { carPos.x - camEye.x, carPos.z - camEye.z };

    if (x == 0)
    {
        camRotation += 0.001f;
        camAt.x = cos(camRotation) + camEye.x;
        camAt.z = sin(camRotation) + camEye.z;

    } else if (x == 1)
    {
        camRotation -= 0.001f;
        camAt.x = cos(camRotation) + camEye.x;
        camAt.z = sin(camRotation) + camEye.z;
    }
    cam->SetEye(camEye);
    cam->SetAt(camAt);
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: IF you find DirectXMath's alignment requirement model around ``XMVECTOR`` or ``XMMATRIX`` too frustrating to use, try using the [SimpleMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2013/01/08/simplemath-a-simplified-wrapper-for-directxmath.aspx) wrapper in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).

Comment: Ah, thanks, using SimpleMath I was able to bypass those annoying access violation errors and finally get myself a camera working with that tutorial, thanks a whole lot!

Comment: The nice thing about SimpleMath is that it is simple... and it trivially interops with the rest of the DirectXMath library so you can move slowly towards using it the way it was designed as you understand it.

Comment: just a friendly reminder, you can use char form like this: GetAsyncKeyState('W') or if you need a special key, like enter, you just swap the char with VK_KEYNAME